# how to give everyone money every 1 second

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to make an economy bot that gives money every second to all users. All the stats of players are stored in a folder named DB, in a file "users.json". (`./DB/users.json`).

Here's an example object of a user's stats:

```json
{
  "(there is users id)": {
    "bal": 28,
    "lastclaim": 1612012406047,
    "lastwork": 1612013463181,
    "workers": 1,
    "rebirths": 1
  }
}
```

So I want all the users that are signed in the economy to get money every second, however, I'm not sure how.

I was also thinking about putting this in a `setInterval` function that triggers every 1000 ms and the `.json` file having a different thing for the not claimed money from work, but I don't know how to check all of the users.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var users = {
  "(there is users id)": {
    "bal": 28,
    "lastclaim": 1612012406047,
    "lastwork": 1612013463181,
    "workers": 1,
    "rebirths": 1
  }
}
setInterval(function(){
   users = Object.entries(users).reduce((init, [key, value] )=> ({...init, [key]: {...value, workers: value.workers + 1 }}),{})
   console.log(users)
},1000)
```

I hope helpful for you

Comment: Yes, very cool, but i want users to be in a completely different file. How can i do it?

Comment: @Wilk import the Json file first and set it as users. const users = require('./DB/users.json'). Or use fs

Comment: Oh! Nevermind, I realised it myself. In the `value.workers + 1` part, i just needed to add "=" after the plus. Thank you for the answer!